# Problem getting Stripe elements to work with vue cli

Tags: iframe, stripe-payments, payment, vue-cli

I recently had a problem where I could not get stripe elements to work in a vue component using vue cli.
I thought the issue was down to 2 warnings in browser stating that iframe content had been blocked from Stripe due to cross origin issue.
I spent 2 days researching this in the hope that it would fix my issue.
It did not! Leaving me stumped.
I then reverted back to an old project that I had Stripe working on and tested it to see if it worked and it did. To my surprise I also noted that I was still getting the same two iframe cross origin errors despite the form working.
So the cross origin errors had nothing to do with my stripe elements isssue!

When you follow the stripe documentation it shows you how to implement Stripe by first adding the stripe js to the header of your index page and in a component function var stripe = Stripe(key) to create the stripe object.

This is where my problem came from.
What I actually had to do was use **var stripe = window.Stripe(key)**. Such a tiny change but it made all the diference! I spent 2 solid days trying to find a solution to this problem so if you are strugglying with getting Stripe elements to work in vue-cli with latest version of vue then try:-
**var stripe = window.Stripe(key)** it just might save you wasting 2 days!